# Apache avoid password protection for a single file

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication, password, virtualhost

I want to protect an entire virtual host in Apache, but I still want to allow public access to a single file. The virtual host proxies all requests to a Tomcat server on the back end. What's the best way to do this?

I tried setting up my virtual host definition as follows, but it still requires a password for the file I want to be exposed publicly:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName example.com

    <Location / >
      Order Allow,Deny
      Allow from all
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Restricted Access"
      AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/secrets.htpasswd
      Require valid-user
    </Location>

    <Location /foo/bar.html>
      Order Allow,Deny
      Allow from all
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both <Location> sections apply to your file, and so they are both processed for it in order.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/sections.html
Your second section doesn't override anything from your first, so the AuthType and Require directives, etc, remain intact.

If you add the directive "Satisfy any" directive (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#satisfy) in the latter section, I believe that should allow all traffic thanks to your "Order Allow,Deny" and "Allow from all".  You can leave out repeating those two directives, though.